# PHP login with session

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I have a problem with my Login, my login only works on the sec attempt.
My code for the secured site is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
   header('Location:login.php');
   exit;
}
?>
```

My login code from **login.php** is

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
    }   
    $myusername = $_POST['user'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);                
    $stmt= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'");
    $count= $stmt->rowCount();
    $dbh=null;
    if($count==0){
        header('Location:loginfail.php');
    }
    if($count==1){
        $_SESSION["user"]= $_POST['user'];
        header('Location:customerinfo.php')
}
>?
```

I tried to check the Session with `print_r($_SESSION)`. The Session starts every time and I can go to the `customerinfo` site after that.
Can someone help me?
Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you run session_start() on your login.php?

Comment: You should read up on sql injection and password hashing.

Comment: `stripslashes` doesn't help prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Have you put session_start() on your login.php at the top?

Comment: Yes @PhiterFernandes

Comment: @jeroen i know but thanks.

Comment: So the first code block is on `customerinfo.php`?

Comment: what are you getting after `print_r($_SESSION)`?

Comment: I tried your code using session_start() at the top of login.php and it worked perfectly. Are you able to see any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if(!$_SESSION["user"]){
   header('Location:login.php');
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but sometimes i get the Error"Wrong Username/Password" but the Username and Password are right.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.